# Can we define all members(including data as well as functions) of a c++ class as private?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I was trying to understand the C++  classes and then I realized that I need at least one public function to set the values of data members in any objects.

is there any method through which I can define define all members(including data as well as functions) of a c++ class as private?

Comment: Well, did you try it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "can"? Are you expecting a compiler error or warning for having nothing public? Or are you wondering if such a class would be useful? Those are different questions.

Comment: NO, I didn't , can you tell me how can I?

Comment: @Aman ...make a class...make everything private (or just don't use any access specifiers at all)

Comment: Your question starts by saying such a thing is utterly pointless despite being possible. Then you ask how to do it? What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you define your class members and do not use any modifiers, all of the members (including the constructor), will be considered as private. Here is a code snippet:

```
class AllMembersPrivate
{
    AllMembersPrivate(); //constructor
    int privateMemberOne;
    int privateMemberTwo;
    int PrivateMethodOne();
}
```

Now note, that you will not be able to create an instance of this class, because the constructor itself has been declared as private.

So, what you probably want, is this:

```
class AllMembersPrivate
{
    int privateMemberOne;
    int privateMemberTwo;
    int PrivateMethodOne();
public:
    AllMembersPrivate(); //constructor
}
```

Comment: unless you wanted to force the construction to only occur from a factory that is mentioned as being a `friend` of the class, then the first option would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can with friends (either functions or other classes)

```
class TheClass
{
    int property;
    TheClass() :property(0) {};
    TheClass(TheClass const&) = default;
    TheClass& operator=(TheClass const&) = default;
    ~TheClass() = default;

    friend TheClass* make();
    friend void modify(TheClass*, int);
    friend int retrieve(TheClass const*);
    friend void unmake(TheClass*);
};

TheClass* make() { return new TheClass; }
void modify(TheClass* obj, int n) { obj->property = n; }
int retrieve(TheClass const* obj) { return obj->property; }
void unmake(TheClass* obj) { delete obj; }
```